# Apresentação de dados no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Olá, estou com problemas no ggplot2 em um histograma.

O código:

```
ggplot(data.combined[1:891,], aes(x = Age, fill=Survived)) + 
  facet_wrap(~Sex + Pclass) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10) + 
  xlab ("Age") + 
  ylab ("Total Count")
```

Com o seguinte código, usando exatamente os mesmos dados de um tutorial estou obtendo um histograma em que o valor de 0 (inicial) está na metade da primeira caixa, já no tutorial a caixa do sujeito começa em zero.

Alguém poderia me ajudar nisso? Estou preocupado porque junto da diferença entre um estar no início e outro no meio eu obtenho distorções na leitura das informações no meu gráfico, prejudicando a interpretação.

Como deveria obter:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como obtenho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo visto você só precisa usar `boundary = 0` no `geom_histogram` para forçar a primeira barra em 0. Como você não forneceu os dados, criei um exemplo, ficou um pouco diferente mas parece ter resolvido:

```
data.combined <- data.frame(Age = rnorm(891, 35, 10),
                            Survived = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 891, TRUE),
                            Sex = sample(c("male", "female"), 891, TRUE),
                            Pclass = 1)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.combined[1:891,], aes(x = Age, fill=Survived)) + 
  facet_wrap(~Sex + Pclass) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10, boundary = 0) + 
  xlab ("Age") + 
  ylab ("Total Count")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá! De verdade, melhorou muito a minha visualização já. Porém, tu saberia me dizer porque ainda tenho algumas distorções para o meu gráfico?
Por exemplo, se tu clicares aqui e observar o dele aos 23:04: https://youtu.be/u6sahb7Hmog?t=23m4s

comparado com o que estou obtendo agora, tu sabes o porquê das distorções entre eu e ele?
Aqui o meu atual:
![Atual](https://scontent-iad3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13254213_1616748428642748_5728964366119335257_n.jpg?oh=17edbe458aca3d88d12e07a2d1d1abd7&oe=57E1883F)

Comment: @GuilhermeHeiden É difícil afirmar apenas olhando as duas imagens, mas eu imagino que possam ser duas causas: 1. Você está usando Windows, e ele OSX, os dispositivos gráficos são diferentes e pode ser que alterem alguma coisa. 2 (mais provável). O vídeo é de 2014, e sabe-se lá quando foi gravado, então as versões do R e do `ggplot2` são diferentes e mudanças podem ter sido feitas. Se você está apenas fazendo o curso, não se preocupe com esses detalhes, quando for de fato criar um gráfico aí sim vale a pena ir atrás dos detalhes.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Molx! Foste de muitíssima ajuda e compreensão, vou seguir então, abraço!